# How do i check if a file has opened streams using java

Tags: java

In windows,if you try to delete a file which has streams opened,it will return false.
Where was in linux,if you try to delete a file which is open,it just deletes the file.
Now i need a mechanism which works in both os to check if a file has streams opened(If the files is used by some other application)

Answer (score 2):

File lock is platform-dependent. 
On some platforms, the file lock is advisory,
which means that unless an application checks for a file lock, 
it will not be prevented from accessing the file. On other platforms, the file lock is mandatory, which means that a file lock prevents any application from accessing the file.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/SetFileLock.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Linux uses advisory locks. Hence applications have to collaborate using locks to communicate on files.

I am not sure if its possible with pure java alone.